# What is the best way to implement android to server communication right now?

Tags: android, mysql, sql-server, server, google-cloud-messaging

I'm working on an android app that will send and receive data from a server where a MySQL database will be stored. The data will be text and images.
I'm confused about the technologies that should be used for fetching data from and to a server. As far as I know it is good practise nowadays to use Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) to send short messages between the server and the android app. So I'm thinking of using GCM for push notifications and to wake up some service on the mobile device so it starts fetching data from the server. But what technology should I use for more text and images?

Comment: HttpUrlConnection , Volley , Retrofit , OkHttp, RoboSpice there is so many libraries you can communicate your Android app with your Server. But you must start to search in Google or Stackoverflow or blog sites. Effort something and ask a question with more specific topic and with code especially.

Answer (score 0):

Use retrofit to submit and fetch data from server. 
https://github.com/square/retrofit